# Preparing search criteria and results to be e-mailed

Tags: perl

I'm getting data to fill out an e-mail template, and I'm wondering if this method is too long. How could I refactor it?

```
sub getEmailData
{
    my $self = shift;

    my $defs = QuickContentFunction::Simple::QuerySearchFieldDefinitions->new();

    my $phParams = decode_json($self->parameters);
    my @aFields = split(/~/, $phParams->{sFields});
    my @aCategories = split(/~/, $phParams->{sCategories});
    my @aValues = split(/~/, $phParams->{sValues});
    my @aConditions = split(/~/, $phParams->{sConditions});

    my $sSummary = $phParams->{sSummary};
    $sSummary =~ s/\'//g;
    my @aSummary = split(/\d/, $sSummary);

    my $phData = { name => $self->name };

    my $mapping = $self->getOperatorMapping();
    for (my $i = 0; $i < scalar(@aFields); $i++) {
        my $phFieldInfo = $defs->getFieldHash( $aCategories[$i], $aFields[$i]);

        my $value = $aValues[$i];
        if ($phFieldInfo->{value_displays}) {
            $value = @{$phFieldInfo->{value_displays}}[$value];

        } elsif ($phFieldInfo->{value_keys}) {
            $value = @{$phFieldInfo->{value_keys}}[$value];
        }

        push( @{$phData->{conditions}}, {
            field    => $phFieldInfo->{field_display},
            operator => $mapping->{$phFieldInfo->{field_type}}->{$aConditions[$i]},
            value    => $value,
            postfix  => $aSummary[$i+1] || undef
        } );
    }

    $phData->{mode} = lc($phParams->{sMode});
    if ($self->hasResults()) {
        $phData->{deals} = \@{decode_json($self->result)};
    }

    return $phData;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

First off, stuff like `my @aFields = split(/~/, $phParams->{sFields});` is a sign of something gone awry. You've just deserialized `$phParams` from a JSON object, so why isn't this just stored in a normal array?

There is no need to write `$i < scalar(@aFields)`, just write `$i < @aFields`.

I have some comments wrt. this snippet:

```
my $value = $aValues[$i];
if ($phFieldInfo->{value_displays}) {
    $value = @{$phFieldInfo->{value_displays}}[$value];
} elsif ($phFieldInfo->{value_keys}) {
    $value = @{$phFieldInfo->{value_keys}}[$value];
}
```

You should always `use warnings;` and `use strict;`. The above won't run without warnings if warnings are on because `@{$phFieldInfo->{value_keys}}[$value]` should be written `${$phFieldInfo->{value_keys}}[$value]`.

Also, the whole thing can be written much shorter:

```
my $value = ${$phFieldInfo->{value_displays}}[$aValues[$i]]
    || ${$phFieldInfo->{value_keys}}[$aValues[$i]]
    || $aValues[$i];
```

*Note:* this isn't functionally identical with the original code, since I'm assuming that array refs at the keys `value_displays` and `value_keys` exists.

This essentially means "pick the first trueish value". Note that values like undef, `0` or the empty string won't be picked. If you want to be able to pick `0` or the empty string, replace `||` with `//`. This requires a recent version of perl (read: not ancient).

The rest looks reasonable. Fixing the stuff I suggested should cut the size a little, and I wouldn't try shortening it further.

Comment: awesome, thanks a lot! The reason the data is stored as a JSON is beyond my control, but I agree, it shouldn't be that way. I actually do have `use warnings` on, but we're on perl version 5.8..could that be why it didn't throw anything? I like your `|| ... ||` construct. Thanks again!

Comment: It should warn even with perl 5.8. That's odd. By the way - using strict is more important than warnings.

Comment: there are few problems with `||`; first `$value` is defined with `my` and used on the same line; second `$value` should start with contents of `$aValues[$i]`; third `undef` or other false value will continue evaluation unlike in OP; and last, autovivification will take place unlike in OP. First two are essential problems while others may not spoil OP logic.

Comment: You're right. I didn't spot that ``$value`` is being reused. Duh.

Comment: I believe I've fixed it now. I'm not used to code where data is being set and reset in this way.

Comment: I caught that as well, I think the current form is appropriate for my needs. I was using strict as well, btw.

Comment: Looking at the code above, I see that I still haven't got it right.

Comment: I've added a note to help others that read my suggestions.

Comment: Ok, now I see. This is actually not what I want, since I need to check if $phfieldInfo->{value_keys} exists. Any other ideas?

Comment: Not really since it isn't an obfuscation contest :) If you just wanted it short and didn't care about readability, you could nest ternary select operators (``<boolean expression> ? <something> : <something else>``), but assuming that the next developer to work with your code is an angry axe murderer who knows where you live - not including yourself (quoted from Damian Conway), you probably shouldn't do that.

Answer (score 3):

Some of the replaced lines are left as comments.

```
sub getEmailData {
    my $self = shift;

    my $defs = QuickContentFunction::Simple::QuerySearchFieldDefinitions->new();

    my $phParams = decode_json($self->parameters);
    # my @aFields = split(/~/, $phParams->{sFields});
    # my @aCategories = split(/~/, $phParams->{sCategories});
    # my @aValues = split(/~/, $phParams->{sValues});
    # my @aConditions = split(/~/, $phParams->{sConditions});

    my ($aFields, $aCategories, $aValues, $aConditions) = 
      map [ split /~/, $phParams->{$_} ],
      qw(sFields sCategories sValues sConditions);

    my $sSummary = $phParams->{sSummary};
    $sSummary =~ tr|'||d; # s/\'//g;
    my @aSummary = split(/\d/, $sSummary);

    my $phData = { name => $self->name };

    my $mapping = $self->getOperatorMapping();
    # for (my $i = 0; $i < scalar(@aFields); $i++) 
    for my $i (0 .. $#$aFields) {
        my $phFieldInfo = $defs->getFieldHash( $aCategories->[$i], $aFields->[$i]);

        my $value = $aValues->[$i];
        if ($phFieldInfo->{value_displays}) {
            $value = $phFieldInfo->{value_displays}[$value];
        } 
        elsif ($phFieldInfo->{value_keys}) {
            $value = $phFieldInfo->{value_keys}[$value];
        }

        push @{$phData->{conditions}}, {
            field    => $phFieldInfo->{field_display},
            operator => $mapping->{ $phFieldInfo->{field_type} }{ $aConditions->[$i] },
            value    => $value,
            postfix  => $aSummary[$i+1] || undef
        };
    }

    $phData->{mode} = lc($phParams->{sMode});
    if ($self->hasResults()) {
        # $phData->{deals} = \@{decode_json($self->result)};
        $phData->{deals} = decode_json($self->result);
    }

    return $phData;
}
```

Comment: I can't tell if the `#$aFields` is a comment...so is it `for my $i (0 .. $aFields)` ? What version of perl is required?

Comment: any perl5 is fine, `$aFields` is array reference so `$#$aFields` is last index for that array (if you're more comfortable with brackets then `$#{$aFields}`)